# How to resolve conflict between zen theme breadcrumb function and Path Breadcrumbs?

Tags: 7, breadcrumbs, theming

Apparently there Path Breadcrumbs module and the [Zen theme's](https://www.drupal.org/project/zen) breadcrumb append title option have a conflict where the Path Breadcrumbs module overrides the theme's implementation of the breadcrumbs. Such that when the PB module is enabled, the theme's breadcrumb trail doesn't append the title to the breadcrumb trail. This leaves me with three options: 1) hack the theme breadcrumb implementation to re-add the titles, 2) implement views page breadcrumbs in code; 3) implement path bread crumbs for all of my pages. None of these options seems particularly pleasant, but I think approaching the theme breadcrumbs will be the least work. Any ideas? or simple workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, more obvious than I'd like to admit: there is a Path Breadcrumbs settings tab where you can configure the theme settings[image] as well as per theme breadcrumb settings. Enabling the theme breadcrumbs for my custom theme solved the problem!.